# Group forming when the group size is equal

Tags: combinatorics, algebra-precalculus

This is from Higher Algebra by Hall and knight.

To find the number of ways in which (m + n) things can be divided into two groups containing m and n things respectively.

The required number is $\color{Blue}{\large\frac{(m+n)!}{m!.n!}}$, but when m=n, the formula becomes $\color{Red}{\large\frac{2m!}{m!.m!.2!}}$, saying that

> "for in any one way it is possible to interchange the two groups
>   without obtaining a new distribution."

Also, the number of ways in which (m + n + p) things can he divided into three groups containing m, n, p things severally is $\color{blue}{\large{\frac{(m+n+p)!}{m!n!p!}}}$ , but if n=p=m, then it becomes $\color{red}{\large\frac{3m!}{m!m!m!3!}}$, stating that

> $\large\frac{3m!}{m!m!m!}$ regards as different all the possible
>   orders in which the three groups can occur in  any one mode of
>   subdivision.

How do we realise that the formula in "Blue" is not taking care of the situation mentioned above by the author? (when we are applying the formula in Blue which is the formula for combination it must take care of the situation of equal group size.)

Why this happens only when the group size is equal?

Also, there is a problem given as follows

> In how many ways can 12 things be divided equally among 4 persons?
>   Answer=369600

Here if we apply $\color{Blue}{\large\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!}=369600}$, but if apply $\color{Red}{\large\frac{12!}{3!3!3!3!4!}=15400}$

Comment: Does the author also consider the case of three groups where $m=n\ne p$ giving $\frac{(2m+p)!}{m!\,m!\,p!\,2!\,1!}$?

Comment: in the case of m+n+p, first they form two groups of m and n+p and then from n+p, two groups of n and p